# How to toggle adjacent cell content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm generating a table from MySQL that looks like the one below. When a user checks the checkbox, I want to color that cell and **ideally** toggle the word "Inactive" to "Active" (and vice versa when it becomes unchecked).

```
<table border="1" width="75%" class="stripeMe">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Accounts</th><th>Status</th><th>Change</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>M. Lamb</td><td class="c2"><span>Inactive</span></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R2C3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>B. Peep</td><td class="c2"><span>Active</span></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R3C3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>J. Spratt</td><td class="c2"><span>Active</span></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R4C3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>H. Dumpty</td><td class="c2"><span>Inactive</span></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R5C3" /></td>
</tr>
```

Based on what I've learned from searching here, I'm able to toggle the cell containing the checkbox and change the adjacent cell word using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e) {
        var bgColor = $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' ? '#f00' : '#fff';
        var txtStatus = $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' ? 'changed' : 'unchanged';
        //toggle the checkbox cell when clicked
        $(this).closest('td').css('background', bgColor);
        //toggle the inactive
        $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span').text(txtStatus);
    });
});
```

I feel like I'm so close, but can't seem to find my way! [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlstuart/fUgUX/) is my test fiddle.

Comment: I do want to thank all of you! I've learned so much from each of your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another option: http://jsbin.com/ahitiv/8/edit#javascript,html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").each(function(idx){
        $(this).click(function(){
           var rowid = idx;
           rowid = "#" + rowid;
           var rowtext = $(rowid).text();
           if (rowtext == "Inactive")
              $(rowid).text("Active");
           else
             $(rowid).text("Inactive");

        });

     });

});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was aiming for! Thank you to all!

Answer (score 0):

You were basicallly missing the `<span>` tag, this will work http://jsfiddle.net/k5VfD/

```
    <table border="1" width="75%" class="stripeMe">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>R2 Col 1</td><td class="c2">R2 C2</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R2C3" /><span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>R3 Col 1</td><td class="c2">R3 C2</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R3C3" /><span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>R4 Col 1</td><td class="c2">R4 C2</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R4C3" /><span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>R5 Col 1</td><td class="c2">R5 C2</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" id="R5C3" /><span></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e) {
        var bgColor = $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' ? '#f00' : '#fff';
        var txtC = $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' ? 'acvtive' : 'Inactive';
        //do something when checked
        $(this).closest('td').css('background', bgColor);
        //Changed here to target the added span. I don't use next() so that
        //this will work even if you play around with the DOM a little.
         $(this).closest('td').find('span').text(txtC);

    });
});
```

Comment: This changes the text of the parent of the checkbox--this isn't the behavior she was asking for.

Comment: @Purmou sorry but the fiddle was different from what she posted, i looked at the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rmf56/

just change last statement with

```
 $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('span').text(txtC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `siblings()` like that doesn't actually make sense—what you're doing is telling it, for each sibling, find the inner span and set its text. If you needed to do that then you would use `siblings().each(function(){...});`.

But since that's not what you want, I changed that line to this:

```
$(this).closest('td').prev().text(txtStatus);
```

We're just selecting the parent td's previous element and setting its text.

Though you can make your code more efficient by chaining it like so:

```
$(this)
    .closest('td')
    .css('background', bgColor)
    .prev()
        .text(txtStatus);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/fUgUX/12/).

I also simplified your ternary. It's using jQuery's `is()` function to check if the checkbox is checked. It returns a boolean and it works great. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You were indeed very close. Here is my solution which is based on your fiddle sample.

Change

```
$(this).closest('td').css('background', bgColor);
```

To

```
$(this).closest('td').prev().css('background', bgColor); 
// finds the nearest TD element and then the PREVIOUS element taking us to the required TD before changing its bg.
```

And I would add this in to update the text

```
$(this).closest('td').prev().text(txtC);
```